# better alternative on for loop verilog

Tags: for-loop, verilog

I am a newbie in verilog. I have been searching online and most of them suggest to not use for-loop in verilog coding. So is there a better alternative to replace for-loop? 
The problem that I am facing now is that I need to perform 1 or 2 for-loop in a case statement. And I have been thinking of better alternatives but come up with none. It will be great if any one of you can shed some light on this.

Example of my code:

```
always @(*)
case (help)
4'd1: for (i=A; i<=20;i=i+B)
       begin temp[i-1]=1; end
4'd2: for (i=A; i<=20;i=i+B)
        begin temp[i-1]=1; B=B+1; end
4'd3: begin
       for (i=A; i<=20;i=i+B)
        begin temp[i-1]=1; B=B+1; end
       for (i=A; i>=1;i=i-B)
        begin temp[i-1]=1; B=B+1; end
      end
default: temp = 0;
```

Comment: @Ari unfortunately my code takes a very very long time to compile. I guess the reason behind this was what Greg mentioned below, that my for-loops are not static.

Comment: No, the static or dynamic nature of the code doesn't have anything to do with the compile time. A code with non-static loop may not synthesize though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For-loops are fine in Verilog, but they need to able to static unroll if you plan on synthesizing. Static unroll means the loop is not depended on any external variables. For example `for(i=0;i<10;i=i+1)` is static. `for(i=A; i<=20;i=i+B)` is not static as it is a depends on the variables `A` and `B`.

You can make a loop static my moving the variables as a condition inside the for-loop. `for(i=A; i<=20;i=i+B)` becomes:

```
tmp_var = A;
for (i=0; i<=20;i=i+1) begin
  if (i==tmp_var) begin
    // ... your logic here ...
    tmp_var = tmp_var+B;
  end
end
```

---

*Issues that need to be addressed beyond the scope of the question:*

They way you are using `B` and `temp` is a little concerning.

- `B` appears to be an input, but you are also incrementing it. For synthesis it is illegal to manipulate an input. If it is an input, then create a local variable with default value as `B` and you may change this value later in the within same always block. If it is not an input, then it is creating latching logic; which is not good and I will cover that next with `temp`.
- `temp` is latching logic. Latching logic are troublesome because timing is critical; knowing when the latch is transparent or closed, and respecting the hold time requirements. The more complex the logic the harder it is to predict. In RTL one way latches are inferred is by incomplete assignments inside an combinational blocks (ie `always @*`). To resolve this, make sure every bit is assigned each pass of the combinational blocks. One way to safe guard this is to assign default values before staring your logic. Example:

  ```
    always @(*) begin
      temp = 0; // default to a constant
      temp_B = B; // default to an input value

      // ... your logic ...
    end
  ```

Comment: Ooh! I didn't know having variables in the for-loop is illegal. Thank you for this tip! By the way, if the if-else statement inside a loop does not have an else, will that create a latch too? Cause the method you suggested have only if without an else.

Comment: One more question: you mentioned that temp is a latching logic and that to solve it requires a default value before hand. Having it assigned to the case's default does not help? How so?

Comment: You need to consider all posable paths. If there way that any bit is not assigned in any path but is assigned in at least one path, then that bit is a latch. The default condition in the case statement is one of several posable paths.

Comment: I see... another question: if I have 2 loops in a case statement, will they be carried out in parallel? or sequential?

Comment: In simulation it is always sequential. Synthesizers will unravel the loops, map it to a truth table, then construct gate-logic based on the truth table. The truth table is calculated sequential based on for-loops; last assignment to a bit wins. The gate-logic can be a mix of parallel and sequential logic mapped to the available gates. The gate-logic will not resemble the RTL logic it was based, but it will be functionally equivalent.

Comment: Also, synthesizers usually have directives for case-statements: parallel_case / full_case. Using the directives is tool specific for Verilog; SystemVerilog added cross-platform keywords `unique case` (parallel_case & full_case), `unique0 case` (parallel_case), & `priority case` (full_case).