# System Verilog: The loop variable is not initialized to a constant ELAB-800

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, synthesis, register-transfer-level

When trying to compile my RTL design that is written in System Verilog, I am using Synopsys Design Compiler, but I am getting the following error message:

> Error: /home/rtl/mydesign.sv:66: The loop variable is not initialized
>   to a constant. (ELAB-800)

Here is the code in question:

```
// Zero out bits from savedbit_loc all the way down to the least significant bit
// We don't know the value of savedbit_loc until the module is instantiated.

assign savedbit_loc = src1- MYPARAM1 - 1;

// Zero out the 
always @(*) begin
    for (int i = savedbit_loc; i >= 0; i--) begin  
        zeroedout[i] = 1'b0;
  end
end
```

MYPARAM1 is a parameters that are set when the module is instantiated.

The line it is complaining about is:

```
for (int i = savedbit_loc; i >= 0; i--) begin
```

My code runs in ncverilog just fine and obtains the correct output.

Is there another way to write this module so that i don't get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming MYPARAM1 and MYPARAM2 are declared as `parameter`s, then make `savedbit_loc` a `parameter` too.

```
localparam int savedbit_loc = MYPARAM1 - MYPARAM2 - 1;
```

Also, always use `always_comb` instead of `always @(*)`

The big advantage is that `always_comb` guarantees to execute at a least once time 0, where as always @(*) waits for an event. This can cause differences in simulation if the block only contains constants on the RHS.

---

Based on your updated question, what you probably want is

```
myval = myval & (32'('1) <<savebit_loc);
```

Comment: I updated the question a bit, please take a look at it now. basically saved_bit depends on inputs coming in at run time, not just static parameters, I forgot that part, so I edited the code.

Comment: I found this answer which I think addresses my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082193/better-alternative-on-for-loop-verilog  Let me know if you have any better ideas please

Comment: It would really help to show a lot more code that explains the intent of what you are trying to do. If you are just trying to mask some bits, then you could do a logical shift.

Comment: Just trying to zero out bits. Basically myval[savedbit_loc:0] =0. But savedbit_loc depends on the value of an input to the module as well as a parameter set at the time of instantiation.